# image size has been increased after i.atcorr

Tags: image, file-size

I have compiled `i.atcorr` and run for different data sets.  The problem is, it is writing the output 4 times of input image. I checked for data types, they are fine. I am not able to catch where exactly problem is. Can anyone suggest me?

I also want to mention that image first processed for toar using grass gui 6.4.4 and then the image passed for `i.atcorr` (customized for our purpose) actually in toar itself it is getting doubled. Is there any problem in gui version of `i.landsat.toar`? I have used for landsat5 tm data path141row43. Please suggest me.

Comment: First, did you check the extent of the computational region?  Second, what is 4 times (bigger, I guess) than which input image?  An image (a Landsat band in this case) stored in GRASS' data base?  Which data types are fine?

Comment: Did you also check, which datatype your Pixels are? Landsat8 is delivered with 12bit/pixel. I'm not familiar with the atcorr procedure in GRASS - but if it outputs 32bit/pixel (single float) that would explain the jump in filesize (if you mean filesize).